# Highlight specific text in one cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, color-codes

I have few values in column I and column H, i have a code which highlights specific words in H column if those words are exactly present in I column.

Drawback is it highlights the works only if they are exactly ditto and are present together, Can any changes be made in the code and make highlight each word even if they are not together

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl0K8.png]

attaching a image of what i want vs what i have, also attaching the existing code.

```
Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range, md As Variant, i As Long, w1 As String, os As Long
    Set c1 = Range("I2")
    Set c2 = Range("H2")
    
    md = Range(c1, Cells(Rows.Count, c1.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(md)
        If md(i, 1) <> "" Then
            w1 = c2.Cells(i, 1).Value
            os = InStr(1, w1, md(i, 1), vbTextCompare)
            While os > 0
                c2.Cells(i, 1).Characters(Start:=os, Length:=Len(md(i, 1))).Font.Color = vbBlue
                os = InStr(os + 1, w1, md(i, 1), vbTextCompare)
            Wend
        End If
    Next i
```

It would be a great help if someone solves my problem.

Comment: Use `Split(md(i, 1), ",")` to get an array of words to highlight, and loop over that.  Don't forget to `Trim()` each word to remove any spaces at the beginning/end.

Comment: Hi, thank for the suggestion, but im very new to VBA code, can u please let me know exactly where to use this @Tim Williams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pattern matching use a Regular Expression.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub markup()

    Dim regex As Object, m As Object, ar
    Dim pattern As String, s As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, k As Long, n As Long, p As Long

    ' Create regular expression.
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    'update sheet
    With ActiveSheet
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            pattern = Replace(.Cells(i, "I"), ",", "|")
            If Len(pattern) > 0 Then
                regex.pattern = pattern
                s = .Cells(i, "H")
                If regex.test(s) Then
                
                    ' markup matches
                    Set m = regex.Execute(s)
                    For k = 0 To m.Count - 1
                        p = m(k).firstindex + 1
                        n = Len(m(k))
                        With .Cells(i, "H").Characters(Start:=p, Length:=n)
                            .Font.Color = vbBlue
                            .Font.Bold = True
                        End With
                    Next
                
                End If                
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hloo, thanks for your time, but im getting a error in `If regex.test(s) Then` line, can u help me out please @CDP1802

Comment: No, windows 10, it says application defined or object defined error, the code is working upto some rows and then error shows, its highlighting words seperated by comma, can it also highlight words seperated by Space?@CDP1802

Comment: Column I has * which must be highlighted in a phrase(The roses are red) in column H, The phrase doesnt have * to be highlighted @CDP1802

Comment: column H: Thick and Warm Mens Daily Cuffed Beanie OR Slouchy Made in USA for USA Knit HAT Cap Womens Kids (One Size, 1.02) Made in USA Black with Visor
Column I: 1.02) Made in Usa Black With Visor
Made in Usa Black With Visor must be highlighted in column H, the code fails here also, Can u do something to help me please@CDP1802

Comment: @NS Ok * has special use in a regex so add another line `pattern = Replace(pattern, "*", "\*")` before `If Len(pattern) > 0 Then`. If you want to split on spaces or comma then none of the words separated by comma must have spaces in them. If so add another replace `pattern = Replace(pattern, " ", "|")`

Comment: Thank you so much, its working fine now

Comment: @NS See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to accept answer.